# Stripe Metadata

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I´m doing some stripe tests and storing few information on "metadata' such as My customer id, (CustomerID=1)

I would like to know if there is some way to query stripe metadata to lookup my customers or should I store stripe CustomerID (cust_XXXXXXXXXXXX) in my database after create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stripe API doesn't support filtering customers on specific metadata at the moment. The list of parameters available for the List Customers API is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_customers).

You should save that information in your own database instead so that you can filter on it easily.